# How to use XPathSelectElement in .Net Core 1.0?

Tags: c#, xpath, asp.net-core, nuget, .net-core

In `.Net 4.X`, this extension method is under `System.Xml.XPath`.

However I'd like to know how could I find/use it in .Net Core? I have a class library.

The porting tool doesn't show anything about `XPathSelectElement`.

Or maybe any replacement in .Net core?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Use http://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net to locate which package you need to refer to.

Comment: Hi Lex Li, you are genius!

Answer (score 7):

You need to add package `System.Xml.XPath.XDocument 4.0.1`. This package provides extension methods that add `System.Xml.XPath` support to the `System.Xml.XDocument` package.

Run below command in Package Manager Console.

```
PM> Install-Package System.Xml.XPath.XDocument -Version 4.0.1
```

You can also install it from NuGet package manager having version `NuGet 2.12` or higher.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Lex Li, we could use [this website](http://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net/) to search the package name. In my case it is: `System.Xml.XPath.XDocument`.